# When pressing Enter in the address bar of a modern browser, is there an interrupt that handles that event?

Tags: language-agnostic, interrupt

Some context: I was witness to an interview not so long ago, where the interviewer asked the interviewee what happens when a user presses the Enter button. A long explanation later, the interviewer explained that this action actually fires an *interrupt* so the CPU can handle the event (*the event* being the user hit Enter in the address bar).

This got me thinking as to whether or not this would actually result in an interrupt. While such low-level system/OS semantics are not my speciality, I was always under the impression that interrupts were mostly (exclusively?) for hardware devices.

So, when a user presses the Enter button in an address bar, is there ultimately an interrupt that causes the CPU to execute the code that loads the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ultimately, the very moment you press a key or move the mouse, the input device generates an interrupt that the CPU services in a dedicated interrupt handler routine, where it reads the data off the device (the key code or the moved distance). And this has nothing to do with the browser per se.